# Disabling ASP.Net 2.0 Web Events

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

Some exceptions (web service calls) of a Web Application are not handled, because I want to show them on a Custom Error Page, passing from the Application_Exception method. 
Porting my Web Application to ASP.Net 2.0, these events started to appear in the Event Viewer (Web Events, new feature of ASP.Net 2.0).

Is there a way to disable ASP.Net 2.0 Web Events, or to avoid the automatic logging in the Event Viewer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can disable [HealtMonitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fwh2ss9.aspx) in the web.config inside the framework folder,
or change the rules to log some exceptions

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to configure health monitoring instead of disabling it. For the exceptions you *don't* want displayed on the custom error page, you'll want the detailed information that is logged by the default health monitoring configuration.